# How to create a HOC using component as parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a HOC that receive a component and insert it inside my `Store` component.
But i just can create it inside my file.

```
const MyComponent: React.FC = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <div>my component</div>
  );
};

const HOC = (props) => (<Store>
  <SignedMotor {...props} />
</Store>);

export default HOC;
```

How can i do it in a separated file ?
Like this:

```
const storeHoc: React.FC = (Component: React.FC) => (
  <Store>
    <Component />
  </Store>
);

export default storeHoc;
```

Answer (score 0):

React has the default prop called `children`. All you need to do is wrap whatever components you want with your HOC and all components inside it will be passed to it as children. Like so:

```
const storeHoc: React.FC = ({children}) => (
  <Store>
    {children}
  </Store>
);

export default storeHoc;
```

Then just wrap any component with it:

```
  <StoreHoc>
    <Component1 />
    <Component2 />
  </StoreHoc>
```

---

Another example straight from the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html):

```
function logProps(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      console.log('Current props: ', this.props);
      console.log('Previous props: ', prevProps);
    }
    render() {
      // Wraps the input component in a container, without mutating it. Good!
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
}
```

In this case you could call it like this: `const EnhancedComponent = logProps(InputComponent);`

Comment: Has the possibility to call storeHoc as a function ?
like `export default storeHoc(Component);`

Comment: Not for this example, no. I'll add a new one